# Sum of four one-dimensional subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have this tricky problem:

Consider four subspaces $E_1, E_2, E_3, E_4\subset\mathbb{R}^{4}$ such that:

a) dim$(E_{k})=3$ for $k=1,2,3,4$.

b) dim$(E_{i}\cap E_{j})=2$ if $i\neq j$,

c) dim$(E_{i}\cap E_{j}\cap E_{k})=1$ if $i$, $j$ and $k$ are all distinct

d) dim$(E_1\cap E_2\cap E_3\cap E_4)=0$

Let's define

$S_{1}:=E_{1}\cap E_2$

$S_2:=E_{2}\cap E_{3}$

$S_3:=E_{3}\cap E_{4}$

$S_4:=E_{4}\cap E_{1}$

and:

$W_{1}:=S_{1}\cap S_{2}$

$W_{2}:=S_{2}\cap S_{3}$

$W_{3}:=S_{3}\cap S_{4}$

$W_{4}:=S_{4}\cap S_{1}$

I have to prove that:

a)dim$(W_1+W_2+W_3)=3$ and

b)dim$(W_1+W_2+W_3+W_4)=4$

I found that it is clear that dim$(W_{i}\cap W_{j})=0$ if $i\neq j$, and dim$(W_{i}+W_{j})=2$.  From this is also clear that $2\leq$dim$(W_1+W_2+W_3)\leq3$, but I'm stuck in this part. I have spent three days trying, but I don't find a way to prove that, for example dim$(W_1\cap(W_2+W_3))=0$. I will appreciate any help that you could give me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look at, say $S_1 + S_2 = E_1 \cap E_2 + E_2 \cap E_3 = (E_1 + E_3) \cap E_2.$ Notice that since $E_1\cap E_3$ is two-dimensional, their sum is $4$-dimensional, and so $S_1 + S_2 = E_2.$ This is true for $S_i$ and $S_j$ where $i$ and $j$ are circularly consecutive. Otherwise, $S_1 + S_3 = S_2 + S_4 = \mathbb{R}^4.$ Now, let's do one of your questions:

$W_1 + W_2 + W_3 + W_4 = S_1 \cap S_2 + S_2 \cap S_3 + S_3 \cap S_4 + S_4 \cap S_1 = (S_1 + S_3) \cap S_2 + (S_1 + S_3) \cap S_4 = S_2 + S_4 = \mathbb{R}^4.$

Comment: I was able to complete the proof. Thank you very much for your help!!! I appreciate it!!!!